# yes/no dialog in app widget

Tags: android, database, dialog, widget

I need to have a yes/no dialog on the widget that allows for directly pressing yes/no on the widget without starting another dialog. Basically putting a `yes` and a `no` button on the widget itself.

While adding a callback with   `views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.xxx, pendIntent);` is no problem, I do not know how to pass a yes/no parameter depending on the user pressing the yes button or the no button.

Each time the user presses yes or no there should be a database update with the answer.

I know I should use a `IntentService` somehow but I am unclear how to connect that to the widget's two buttons.

ps I would also be thankful for any hint/link to an example widget/app which shows how to best design the layout for such a yes/no dialog on a widget

Many thanks